# Excel SUM VLOOKUP Reference Column Indexes in Another Cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

If I wanted to SUM multiple columns from a VLOOKUP I could do

```
=SUM(VLOOKUP(A2,G22:J24,{2,3},FALSE))
```

However, I want a user to be able to choose the column indexes. I have a cell X2 with contents `2,3`. I want to replace my VLOOKUP column index `{2,3}` with a reference to X2.

I have tried

```
=SUM(VLOOKUP(A2,G22:J24,"{" & X2 & "}",FALSE))
```

but it is not working. Do you have any ideas of how I can incorporate this in?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

use this array formula that builds an array from the string:

```
=SUM(INDEX(G22:J24,MATCH(A2,G22:G24,0),N(IF(1,MODE.MULT(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(ROW($2:$4),X2)),ROW($2:$4)*{1,1}))))))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]